# Main window reference becomes null when closing child window

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

In my `main.js`, I create my main window normally (`let mainWin = null`, initialized on startup), and when a certain buttn is pressed, I add child window.

```
let createNoteWin = null;

function createNoteEditWindow() {
    createNoteWin = new BrowserWindow({ parent:mainWin, modal: true, width: 350, height: 500 , frame: false, show: false});
    createNoteWin.on('close', function() {mainWin = null});
    createNoteWin.loadFile('src/addNote.html');
    createNoteWin.isResizable = false;
    //createNoteWin.webContents.openDevTools();
}

ipcMain.on('open-noteedit-window', function newNoteWindowIPC(event, arg) {  
    createNoteEditWindow();
    createNoteWin.show();
})
```

However, when I close my child window, once another button is pressed, the reference to my main window suddenly becomes `null`:

```
ipcMain.on('close-noteedit-window', function closeNoteeditWindowIPC(event, arg) {
    mainWin.webContents //works fine
    createNoteWin.close(createNoteWin);
    mainWin.webContents; //throws an error since mainWin is null now, for some reason
})
```

Does anyone know why/how this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the 5th line, you do exactly what you complain about:

```
    createNoteWin.on('close', function() {mainWin = null});
```

This sets `mainWin` to `null` ("the reference to my main window suddenly becomes null"). Perhaps you meant this instead?

```
    createNoteWin.on('close', function() {createNoteWin = null});
```

Comment: Oh my god, you're right! Sometimes you get blind when looking at your own code for too long. Thanks!

Comment: Schachblindheit, happens to the best of us :)